# After DragDrop.DoDragDrop other controls with in the grids are not able to select(not responding)

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid

I am working on drag and drop functionality with xamdatagrid.I have implemented the drag & drop functionality as mentioned below.

1)  I have created a PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event and in this event I am calling the DragDrop.DoDragDrop() method.
2)  I have one more MouseMove event in this I am getting the selected row from the grid.This selected row I am using in the above PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown event for creating the drop data.

My problem is I have a dropdown(combo box) in the same grid. Since DragDrop.DoDragDrop() is a synchronize methods and it is calling from the PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown, it will not release the mouse event until drop to target and dropdown selection will not work properly.

I tried by setting Boolean flags also but I am not able to distinguish dragdrop and control selection(dropdown selection) from PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown method. I need to call the DragDrop.DoDragDrop() only whenever I am performing drag drop not selecting the dropdown in the grid row. How can I identify the operation is drag drop or dropdown selection?

Is there any other alternative to enable the mouse events without waiting for the DragDrop.DoDragDrop() result.

```
private void PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown (object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            //record presenter I am setting PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown so I am doing the this
            var grid = (sender as DataRecordCellArea).FieldLayout.DataPresenter as XamDataGrid;
            if (grid != null)
                {
itemName = variableViewModel.OriginalPrimaryKey, variableViewModel.Value, variableViewModel.Variable.GuiDisplayUnits;
var data = new DataObject();
                    data.SetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, itemName);
                    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(grid, data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
                }
        }
```

//This for getting the selected row

```
private void KeywordMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
 {
    var grid = (sender as DataRecordCellArea).FieldLayout.DataPresenter as XamDataGrid;
            if (grid != null)
            {
                //we have editable and not ediable columns.previously we faced issue with noe editable column drag so this added
                //Cell area will get for editable and presenter will get for non editable fields.This will get the selected row
                var drcellarea = e.Source as DataRecordCellArea;
                var drpresenter = e.Source as CellValuePresenter;

                DataRecord dataRecord = null;
                if (drcellarea != null)
                {
                    dataRecord = drcellarea.DataContext as DataRecord;
                }
                else if (drpresenter != null)
                {
                    dataRecord = drpresenter.DataContext as DataRecord;
                }

                if (dataRecord != null)
                {
                    var selectedItem = dataRecord.DataItem as VariableViewModel;
                    viewmodel.SelectedItem = selectedItem;
                }
            }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing any code it is quite difficult to know exactly what the issue is, but try calling the `DragDrop.DoDragDrop` in the `MouseMove` handler to see if it resolves your problem. Something like this:

**EDIT:**

```
    private void KeywordMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var grid = (sender as DataRecordCellArea).FieldLayout.DataPresenter as XamDataGrid;
        if (grid != null && e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            itemName = variableViewModel.OriginalPrimaryKey, variableViewModel.Value, variableViewModel.Variable.GuiDisplayUnits;
            var data = new DataObject();
            data.SetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, itemName);

            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(grid, data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
    }
```

I have modified your `KeyboardMouseMove` handler to show what I mean. This now contains the code from your PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown handler which you can now remove. I assume that you have a `Drop` handler on the target `Element` that gets the Data Object out of the `DragDrop` operation and processes it.

Comment: I have two scenario.While drag and drop a cpolumn it is fine and it should exicute the below code.But if i have a dropown in the grid then the same code will execute and since we are using the asynchronous DragDrop.DoDragdrop() it will not give the selected item in the dropdown.I shoukd call the DoDragdrop only whenever i am draging.Dropdown selection should not call.

Comment: Are you able to post the relevant code? (ok just popped up as I was typing)

Comment: I have two scenario. While drag and drop a grid column/row it is fine to call DoDragdrop  but it should not call while selecting a dropdown from the grid column.
If it call the DoDragdrop  then the dropdown selection will not work because DragDrop.DoDragdrop() is a synchronous call and it will not leave the mouse event until drop the object.

Comment: If you start your drag drop in the MouseMove handler and check if the left button is pressed it will not trigger when seleting a drop down from the Grid column, but will still work for dragging a grid/column.

Comment: so you are saying i need to call the dodragdropas mentioned in you comment right?

Comment: If i will write the above code in the KeywordMouseMove then, normal drag drop dropdown select functionality will work.Since i have a noneditable column in the grid,i am getting e.LeftButton  state as "released"(it will not call Dodrag loop) and not able to drag these column.

Comment: I must admit I am not familiar with the Infragistics XamDataGrid so am unaware of how it handles mouse events/non-editable columns etc. As an alternative approach, are you able to make use of the DragEnter event on the ComboBox or the QueryContinueDrag event?